# is it possible to use regex to ignore blocks of text when reading a file

Tags: python, regex, count, file-read

Not sure i'm looking at this from the wrong angle but i'm a bit of a beginner and a bit out of my depth. I'm trying to ignore multiline comments when reading in a  file so I can count the number of lines of code in a .sas file (just a text file). I can get my code to find commentts that are split over 2 line like so

```
/* comment
comment*/
```

however not like this

```
/* comment
comment
comment */
```

my code is

```
for file_name in find_files(d):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        def remove_comments(line):
            is_in_comment = False
            line = line.strip()
            if line.startswith('/*'):
                is_in_comment = True
                return 0
            elif line.endswith('*/'):
                is_in_comment = False
                return 0

            return 0 if is_in_comment else 1

        count = sum(remove_comments(line) for line in f if line.strip())
        print(count)
```

which doesnt work for multiline comments. i have managed to find the multiline comments by using regex. here is the code, the only way I can think of this to work is to write back to the file by using re.sub() then doing the count. is is possible to ignore the regex matches when reading in? or am i way off?

```
for file_name in find_files(d):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
        multiline_comments = re.findall(pattern, data, re.DOTALL)
        print(multiline_comments)
```

Comment: couldn't you just read the file line by line and check it using a pattern for multiline. If it contains the start comment block without an end, use a bool flag that lets you ignore the next lines in your counter until you hit an end comment block, then parse as normal until the next comment block.

Comment: i ended up doing it this way :)